# Safari 9: "Safari can't show the file ____ in the Finder." Errors

Tags: safari, macos

I've got an odd one here with Safari on an OS X 10.11.3 workstation.  When the user downloads a file, they receive the following message every time they attempt to show the file via Safari's download menu:

[image]

Error:

[image: Safari Error]

The files are actually on the file system and can be opened in Finder, etc. Safari simply throws this error every time the user attempts to reveal the file.

Any idea as to what is going on here?

Comment: Try resetting the downloads location in Prefs/general - or set it to somewhere else, then back again.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately tried this multiple times already @Tetsujin to no avail.